# Destroy/ finish previous activities from the current fragment in android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, destroy, activity-finish

I have been developing this application for quite a while now and came up with this bug in the app. Initially when the application loads for the first time, it starts from the **home activity.** Then the user interaction will navigate application to **activity1** which uses **fragment1.** The fragment1 has a button. If the user clicks on that button,the activity1 calls finish() and loads **activity2** by calling startActivity().Also when the user clicks on the hardware back button from the fargment1, the application returns to the Home activity.

So the real issue here is that, when I am at activity2 and finish() the activity the application will show the Home activity. But i want to completely close the application on pressing back from the activity2.

The following is the code which starts the activity2 form the fragment1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity)context).finish();
```

I get that the Home activity has never been finish()-ed.

So how do I destroy the activity1 and home activity on navigating to the activity2, and make the activity2 only remaining activity in the application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach: use start activity for result instead of start activity and finish it in onActivityResult.

Second apparoach: Register a local broadcast in each required activity and in its receiver, finish it. From **activtity2** send this broadcast. This will finiah all those activities in stack having that broadcast registered. I have used this approach for Logout implementation in many apps and it works well.

Comment: thnks ... ill try that out

Comment: it works.I tried the second approach as i saw that to be more promising and suitable to my application.

Comment: :) ... this is my first stackoverflow post ... so didnt know i had to accept an answer... anyways its accepted now.. thnx anyways

Answer (score 2):

Ok so this is what i did (according to @seema):

in the home activity i registered a broadcastreciever in OnCreate() method of the activity.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction("com.example.CUSTOM_INTENT");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("==>","Broadcast Recieved.");
        finish();

    }
};

public void finish() {
    super.finish();
};
```

then in the activity2 i send out the broadcast

```
Intent local = new Intent();
    local.setAction("com.example.CUSTOM_INTENT");
    sendBroadcast(local);
```

This worked out as I required it to be. 
Thus any activity can be destroyed from any other activity.